# Find item in listview with gridview and WPF

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a way to know if my listview contains a value. Below is my code.

```
public class OnlineUserList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

<ListView x:Name="lvOnlineUsers" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="lvOnlineUsers_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="lvOnlineUsersGridView" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Online Users" Block.TextAlignment="Center" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Name="tbOnlineUsersGridView" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=lblLabel}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

public void AddUserToList(string username)
{
   lvOnlineUsers.Items.Add(new OnlineUserList { Name = username, Color = "Black" });
}
```

Now this is where am having issue

```
public void RemoveUserFromList(string username)
{
   if(lvOnlineUsers.Items.Contains(username))
       lvOnlineUsers.Items.Remove(username);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn MVVM.

In the mean time, put the items in an `ObservableCollection` and assign it to the listview's ItemsSource property in your codebehind. Thereafter, repeat after me: Never, ever touch `lvOnlineUsers.Items`. Never, never, never. Forget that it exists. Everything you do, you interact with the `ObservableCollection`. Search it, add items to it, remove items from it. The UI will magically and mysteriously update itself.

I'm going to assume this is in `MainWindow`. If this is in a different view, the constructor will have a different name.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lvOnlineUsers.ItemsSource = _onlineUsers;
}

private ObservableCollection<OnlineUserList> _onlineUsers 
    = new ObservableCollection<OnlineUserList>();

public void AddUserToList(string username)
{
   _onlineUsers.Add(new OnlineUserList { Name = username, Color = "Black" });
}


public void RemoveUserFromList(string username)
{
    //  We don't search _onlineUsers for the string username, because 
    //  _onlineUsers doesn't contain strings. It contains your user class. 
    //  So instead, we look for the user class instance that has the name
    //  we want. 
    var found = _onlineUsers.FirstOrDefault(ou => ou.Name == username);

    if (found != null)
    {
        _onlineUsers.Remove(found);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ed, you are genius. It works as expected. I've mark this as answer. Thanks in a million times

Answer (score 0):

Until you have looked into MVVM, try this:

```
for(int i = lvOnlineUsers.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    OnlineUserList item = lvOnlineUsers.Items[i] as OnlineUserList;
    if (item != null && item.Name == username)
        lvOnlineUsers.Items.Remove(lvOnlineUsers.Items[i]);
}
```